# Copying data from a user form to worksheet for multiple item of data

Tags: vba

I'm trying to move data captured in a form into excel. There are a number of lines within the form and data should only be moved if data is entered.

I have a form which dependent on the division populates the name value of any employees within that division.  There could be 2 or 50 so I have set up 50 txtname boxes to be populated. Based on the value in the name box the correct reference number is returned using vlookup.  The inputter will then enter a variable amount into the txtUnits boxes if the employee has units within the period.

The code below I have used for line one of the form will work but not sure how to make it work for all 50 lines without copying the code 50 times and changing the txt box number reference number etc.

I need to move the employee name, reference number and units for each line if units are greater than zero but also move the division and date worked as constant values

Is this possible to simplify.  I've been looking at loops but not sure how to start with this.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Addto As Range
Set ws = Sheet2
Set Addto = ws.Range("c65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

With ws

If txtUnits1 <> "" And txtName1.Value <> "" Then ' The txtUnits box are 
numbered 1 to 50
Set Addto = ws.Range("c65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
If txtUnits1.Value > 0 Then Addto = txtName1.Value ' The txtName boxes 
are also numbered 1 to 50
If txtUnits1.Value > 0 Then Addto.Offset(0, 1).Value = cboDivision.Value
If txtUnits1.Value > 0 Then Addto.Offset(0, 2).Value = 
txtReference1.Value ' The txtReference boxes are alos numbered 1 to 50
If txtUnits1.Value > 0 Then Addto.Offset(0, 3).Value = 
txtDateWorked.Value
If txtUnits1.Value > 0 Then Addto.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtUnits1.Value
End With


Dim cControl As Control

For Each cControl In Me.Controls
If cControl.Name Like "txt*" Then cControl = ""
If cControl.Name Like "cbo*" Then cControl = vbNullString
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Bettter choose formulas or VB - it is possible to combine both, but you can do same for simple formulas in VB without copy/paste or maintenance problems. In case you are not sure about navigation, record some keyboard shortcuts (ctrl+arrows or home, end, etc.) by macro and check results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If text boxes are properly named like  `txtName1` to `txtName50`,  `txtUnits1` to `txtUnits50` and `txtReference1` to `txtReference50`  then may try simple looping like this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Addto As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'better to use sheet name instead of Codename
    For i = 1 To 4  ' 4 for test purpose only change to 50
        If Me.Controls("txtUnits" & i).Value <> "" And Me.Controls("txtUnits" & i).Value <> "" Then
        Set Addto = ws.Range("c65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Addto.Value = Me.Controls("txtName" & i).Value '
        Addto.Offset(0, 1).Value = cboDivision.Value
        Addto.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.Controls("txtReference" & i).Value
        Addto.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtDateWorked.Value
        Addto.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.Controls("txtUnits" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I've amended as per your suggestion but getting an error on the line -  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") as subscript out if range. Any suggestions

Comment: it is nothing of problem. you may use your old syntax if it is working correct. I just wanted to use the Sheet Name as displayed at sheet Tab. Code name of sheet is displayed in VBA project window in property tab when sheet is selected in project window. Use any name as you wish. I used my Sheet2  for test purpose only. Make necessary change and try hope it will work **if all the text boxes are named properly**

Comment: Thanks for the advice its now getting past this error however it is now transferring any lines that meet the criteria but always ends as       could not find the specified object for line                                                                    If Me.Controls("txtUnits" & i).Value <> "" And Me.Controls("txtEmployee" & i).Value <> "" Then                                                         Is the way the code is ended?

Comment: seems some text box name spells different.. When error occurs, which  line of the code is being highlighted?  Keep your mouse on "i" and would find which text box is the  problem.

Comment: Found the incorrect box name and finishes ok now. Thanks for help

Comment: One last question.  I could do with looping through combo boxes.  Again labeled 1 to 40.  I have tried the same logic but couldn't get it to work.  How would I get the code to loop through combo boxes at the same time?